# For loops won't nest

Tags: python

I'm writing a script to compare two csv files. The plan is for the script to find items with the same ID and send them to a third csv.

I'm using a nested for loop for this. It should pick a line in the first file and then compare it to each line (one at a time) in the second. So far so good.

The script should repeat this for every line in the first file. However, after some debugging I found that the script only compares the first line with each line in the second before stopping. The other lines are never compared.

I can't see why for the life of me. I'm already cringing in case this turns out to be a schoolboy error but thought it would be worth asking the community.

Any ideas?

```
outdata = []
newPrices = open(csv1)
oldPrices = open (csv2)
priceComparison = open (csv3)

new=csv.reader(newPrices, delimiter=',')
old=csv.reader(oldPrices, delimiter=',')
writer=csv.writer(priceComparison,delimiter=',')
for row1 in new:
    print(row1[0])
    for row2 in old:
        print(row1[0]) #Seems to be sticking on the first value and not looping the first for loop
        if row1[0].upper == row2[0]:
            print("row: ", row)
            outdata.append([row1])
            outdata.append([row2])
        
print(outdata)
writer.writerows(outdata)
```

Comment: You would be better off using pandas DataFrames: Less code and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but my guess is that `csv.reader` returns an iterator, which can only be consumed once. Hence why you only loop through `old` once. Try putting the lines in lists before traversing them, like this:

```
new = list(csv.reader(newPrices, delimiter=","))
old = list(csv.reader(oldPrices, delimiter=","))
```

Here's a link to the documentation in case it's helpful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

Comment: Spot on. Thank you for the quick response. It turns out that the writer object wasn't sufficient either. I had to use csv.DictWriter in the end